# How to install vue3 beta using vue/cli?

Tags: vue.js

Right now vue3 is in beta and I want to try it.

Is there a way using @vue/cli to install the vue3 beta? if so, How?

Comment: You should look at this repo : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli-plugin-vue-next

Answer (score 1):

You need the latest version of @vue/cli and then run `vue add vue-next` in an existing Vue CLI project.

This will:

- Add Vue 3 and the new Vue 3 Compiler to your project
- Configure webpack to use the new vue compiler
- Install Vuex 4 and vue-router 4 beta (or alpha dunno where they are rn) if the older versions are in your project
- Codemods for compatibility

More Info [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli-plugin-vue-next)

However, not every package that works with Vue2 will work with this Vue3. 
If all you want to try out is the new composition-api, there is a plugin which you can add which is still using Vue2 but with many of the composition-apis Features, probably all non-breaking changes? You install that by either running

`npm install @vue/composition-api`

or

`yarn add @vue/composition-api`

and then install it like this before using other APIs:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api';

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi);
```